# How can I set up a way to automatically calculate: (goal number/new visitors)

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up a goal which will count the amount of sign ups I get on my site. I need to divide this number by the amount of new visitors in order to get my conversation rate.

From what I can tell, the goal result is

```
number of times goal is reached/unique visitors
```

Is there a way to change it to

```
number of times goal is reached/visitors who have never been to the site before
```

Is there a way to set this up so it is calculated automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, on a side note, I think that your calculation should probably be modified to use "number of times goal is reached for **new visitors**" instead of just "number of times goal is reached". Otherwise the ratio would be using the total number of goals including people who have visited the site before and be larger than it should be (you could potentially have more than 100% conversion rate).

As an answer to the question, I'm not aware of a way to calculate a custom metric. However, if my note above is correct then it would be possible to create an additional profile that is filtered to only include new visitors. Then the original goal result would be what you want.

**Update - How to create the filter:**

To create the profile filter settings, go to the "Analytics Settings > Profile Settings" screen and click on "Add Filter". In the screen that comes up use the following settings:

- Add new Filter for Profile
- Filter Name: New Visitors
- Filter Type: Custom filter
- Click the "include" radio button
- Filter Field: Visitor Type
- Filter Pattern: New
- Case Sensitive: No

Also, as @yahelc mentions, you could use an Advanced Segment to apply a similar filter to back-dated data.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ewan. I have set up the goal so that it is only reached upon completion of a brand new sign up, so I think using the goal number will be okay? Could you please elaborate on creating an additional profile that is filtered to only include new visitors? I'm not sure how to do that and am not having any luck searching around. Thanks again.

Comment: In addition to creating a new profile (which, though more robust, would not be a help for retroactive data), you can also apply an advanced segment for New Visitors only, to filter down to only "first visit" sessions.